# android google maps onMapReady not executed even after calling getMapAsync

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Integrated google maps in android but OnMapReady() call back method is not called when moved from adapter class to this Map_Activity.class.

```
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(Maps_location.this);


//Call back method
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(this);
}

//Adapter class using Intent through context to move to maps activity

holder.loca_edit_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Maps_location.class);
                intent.putExtra("act", "edit_act");
                intent.putExtra("loc_name", loc_name);
                intent.putExtra("lat", loc_lat);
                intent.putExtra("lng",loc_lng);
                intent.putExtra("loc_addrs",loc_addrs);
                intent.putExtra("loca_flat",loc_flat_no);
                intent.putExtra("loca_landmark",loc_landmark);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: whereas the callback method onMapReady is called when moved from any activity to that maps activity through intent

Comment: are you specifying the key properly?

Comment: Yup, The Google map key was specified properly and the map is loading properly as Already stated. The Only issue is that on moving from Fragment to activity this scenario pertains.

Comment: can you tell me where are you calling your  onMapReady callback? means in onCreate() method or onResume()?

Comment: Not in onResume(), Just declared that  onMapReady callback outside the onCreate as an overidden method

Comment: and from where you are calling map fragment?

Comment: Calling from a separate adapter class using intent to reach Maps_activity. I have not used fragment for maps page instead used activity.

Comment: can you add the code so that I can know where are you writing your this portion of code mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(Maps_location.this);

Comment: By the way I have intialized the map fragment within the oncreate

Comment: Remove it from onCreate() and trying doing it in onResume(). You may get your expected result.

Comment: I have tried it on putting it on onResume but still it perists.

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem whenever getMapSync get called it requires some time to execute the call back method. Instead of using any timeout delay, I have put all the conditions inside the onMapReady so map object will not be null, then use any functions on map, Simple :)

Comment: thats great you found a solution'